# Is the "satanic verses" story true?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, shaitan

I'm talking about the story where Muhammad (s.a.w.) was reciting surah Najm and shaytaan whispered some ayahs and Muhammad (s.a.w.) ended up reciting these ayahs because he thought it was Jibreel reciting these ayahs.

If this is true, this means Muhammad (s.a.w.) could not tell the difference between Jibreel and shaytaan. How can I possibly argue against this? Please give me proof that this story is false.

Comment: link please , because i need reference to make more recherche !

Comment: shortly the authentic ahadith doesn't mention the part of satan verses as in bukhari : https://sunnah.com/bukhari/17/4 
it's mentioned in week ahdith !! and it's mention in one that the satan said this verses and people thought it's from the prophet and it's also week !
so the authentic ahadith doesn't mention the story with satanic verses !

Comment: i think all this exist in a Wikipedia article ... the arabic version of article mention that it's not authentic with references https://www.wikiwand.com/ar/%D9%82%D8%B5%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%BA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%82

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have prior knowledge about how authenticity of Hadith is established in Islamic scholarship:

Ibn Kathir, one of the earliest and most respected commentator of the Quran mentions this tradition while commenting on verse 22:52, he says that this tradition does not come to us with any Sahih (authentic) ***isnad*** (chain of transmitters who passed it down from the Prophet) and that all known isnad for this story are ***mursal*** (chronologically broken\interrupted) and hence its authenticity is in doubt.

For reference you can see Ibn Kathir's commentary, there is an abridged english translation available but you can find the full arabic version [online here](https://muflihun.com/22/52?tafid=1592) and maybe get it translated by someone(upwork maybe).

Comment: Ibn Kathir is by no means an early commentator.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Some of the early Islamic scholars used to support this story. They weren't any small scholars. They were very big and prestigious scholars.

Comment: @G.Bach He doesn't need to be an early commentator to point out that the isnad is mursal, hence da'if.

Comment: @curiosity Which early ones? al-Bayhaqi, the famous early hadith scholar and historian stated, "This story has not been proved to be correct by the rules of reporting." Secondly, with narrations it's not a matter of prestige but of proof, and here the hadiths are mursal, you can check al-Albani's book on this where he details all the turuq of the hadith and gives the takhrej of each one of them.

Comment: According to Dr. Yasir Qadhi, there is no authentic version of the satanic verses. Every version in Tabari and Wahadi is weak and none goes back to RasulAllah sAaws. The strongest goes back to a tabi'i. Even ibn Hajar and ibn Taymiyyah admit this. Do you guys know about the version that goes back to a tabi'i?

Comment: @curiosity mursal means that teh tabi'i said the Prophet said that... or the prophet did so he didn't quote a sahabi that's what I understand as a hadith which goes back to a tabi'i. Note that however Uma and John Doe seem to qualify a mursal ahdith as da'if by default this isn't and wasen't the case for neither of the 4 Imams. Especially abu hanifa and Malik had directly known tabi'in so they would have a chance to better qualify their hadith.

Comment: @Medi1Saif  My error that's not what I meant

Comment: @curiosity Ibn Hajar and Ibn Taymiyya are not early scholars (they lived in the 15th and 14th century respectively). al-Albani discusses this in his book on this subject, do you want me to write an answer based on it? (Also check the book "The biography of the Prophet and the Orientalists" vol2 it has a nice discussion of that)

Comment: @JohnDoe If you think your answer can convince me that the satanic verses story is absolutely false, then please go ahead. Thanks.

Comment: @curiosity Okay, I wont cover everything so I need to know the reasons as to why you may think that this innovation is true?

Comment: @JohnDoe Well, there are many versions of this story. When a story has many versions, it kinda makes you think that something like this must have really happened. Another reason is that Ibn Hajar and Ibn Taymiyya believed it. According to Dr. Yasir Qadhi, they were very prestigious scholars.

Comment: @JohnDoe Another reason why part of me believes this story is that it somehow "completes" Bukhari's version of the story. According to Bukhari's version, Muhammad (s.a.w.) was reciting Surah Najm and after he finished reciting, all the muslims, jinns and idolators prostrated behind Muhammad. Bukhari's version makes no mention of the satanic verses. It makes you wonder, "Why did the pagans/idolators prostrate behind Muhammad?". The satanic verses story pretty much gives Bukhari's version a sense of completeness. It gives further explanation to why the pagans prostrated behind Muhammad (s.a.w)

Comment: @JohnDoe And the final reason why I believe this story is simply because I'm mentally weak. I can be very gullible at times, especially when it comes to things like religion. I have no way to prove it to myself that satanic verses is not true. I keep asking myself "If this story is false, then why did such great scholars like Ibn Hajar and Ibn Taymiyyah believe it?"

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm still waiting for your answer brother.